# Use f.select for to choose nested object; Couldn't find Item with ID=1 for Quote with ID=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, apache-cocoon

I have a quote system and I'm choosing Items to add to quotes. quotes and items are associated through a 3rd table (quote_items). I use cocoon gem to create quote.item attributes, which in my case is only item id of the item to be attached to the quote. From there I want to extract all the item attributes that are saved in the DB for the selected item. After trying to create a quote choosing one item I'm getting this error message: Couldn't find Item with ID=1 for Quote with ID=  when trying to create the quote.

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

  has_many :quote_items 
  has_many :quotes, through: :quote_items, dependent: :delete_all
  # validates_uniqueness_of :part_num , scope: [:quote_id]  
end

class Quote < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :quote_items
  has_many :items, through: :quote_items, dependent: :delete_all
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
end
```

in quotes controller

```
  def new
    @quote = Quote.new
    @item = @quote.items.build 
  end

  def create
    @quote = Quote.new(quote_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @quote.save
        format.html { redirect_to quote_path(@quote) }
        format.json { redirect_to quotes_path, status: :created, location: @quote }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to quotes_path }
        format.json { redirect_to quotes_path, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def quote_params
  params.require(:quote).permit(:name,:company,:email,:quote_num, :quantity, :notes, items_attributes: [:id,:_destroy, :part_num, :description, :price, :lead_time, :quote_quantity])
end
```

quote form

```
 <%= f.fields_for :items do |i| %>
   <%= render 'item_fields', :f=> i %>  
 <% end %>   

 <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Part', f, :items, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

_item_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 form-font">
      <%= f.select :id, options_from_collection_for_select(Item.all, :id, :part_num), required: true, label: "Part Number" %>
    </div>   
  </div>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 form-font">
      <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove Part", f, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
    </div>  
  </div><br>  
</div>
```

QuoteItem

```
class QuoteItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :quote
  belongs_to :item
end
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, what's the problem here?

Comment: @BrianKung sorry the issue is that I'm trying to add items to the quote and getting this:  "Couldn't find Item with ID=1 for Quote with ID="

Comment: I'd recommend looking at what HTML is generated on the frontend as a result of the `f.select ....` statement and debugging why it isn't working

Comment: @BrianKung it's not inserting the record into the DB so there's nothing to generate on the front end. The issue starts with the fact that it's not saving the quote to the DB because it can't match the item to the quote.

Comment: I'm going to pass on this question with the feedback that it's really hard to read and understand. I'd recommend clarifying exactly *when and how the error is triggered, what happens, and what you expect to happen.*

Comment: Edited to make more clear.

Comment: Your `f.select` option should not be trying to modify the `:id` of the object. Rails assigns that number for you. Also, from what I see here, you may be better served with a `has_many_and_belongs_to` relationship, but I can't see all of your code to know for sure.

Comment: @Martin thanks but It's still not working unfortunately. 
Also, has_and_belongs_to_many is identical to has_many :through, except the join table/model is implicit.

Comment: Is this rails 5? How does your `QuoteItem` model look?

Comment: @nathanvda Yes it is Rails 5. Just added the QuoteItem model up in the question.

Comment: UPDATE: Issue was fixed by adding accept_nested_attributes_for :the_joined_model as well as for the nested model!